# convert itk (nifti file) to polydata image (.vtk)

Tags: python, vtk, itk, nifti

I am working with MRI database with `nifti`format (.nii) but I want to convert them to polydata images `.vtk`.
I used many different methods: like miconv, itksnap, I download vtk, itk, and itkvtkglue...
But no one give me a good results.
So please help me.

Comment: What you seem to be looking for is image segmentation (look it up).

Can you provide some inputs and results (or screenshots of them) ITK-SNAP etc are giving you, and explain why you are not satisfied with the results?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly `nii` files are volumetric data so you cannot just "convert" it to polygonal data unless you create an [isosurface](https://vtkplotter.embl.es/content/vtkplotter/actors.html#vtkplotter.actors.Volume.isosurface) out of it, try:

```py
from vtkplotter import load
vol = load('myfile.nii') #vtkVolume
vol.isosurface().show()
# or convert to vtk format:
vol.write('newfile.vti')
```